# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Android

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate Firebase cloud messaging with Android. I have created my account on Firebase and integrated with the app and have sent a message from Firebase console. The app received the message. So far, things like this seem working.

My question is that how can I connect Firebase with my own database server, which is consisting of MongoDB, to check for the data of users against to whom a notification is to be sent? Can some one guide me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a number of steps, it is probably too long to post here, but since you just asked for guidance, I'll try to run through the steps involved.

- Your Android app will need to send its FCM token the server running your MongoDB instance. Referencing [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) FCM documentation page, you'll need to implement `sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);` in the `onTokenRefresh()` method.
- Your server will need to be listening for clients sending their FCM token. This could be an HTTP endpoint listening for POST requests with a client token and username. It can then store the details in your database. (Remember to use HTTPS where possible.)
- Enable the Cloud Messaging API: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=insert-project-id-here
- You can send FCM messages from the server running MongoDB using the [Firebase HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send), but first you'll need to authorize your server to do so. Instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server). You will get an authorisation token that needs to be included in the HTTP header of all API requests.
- Once you have a valid token you can send an HTTP POST request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send`, where the body contains details of the message. [This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send) contains a description of the API endpoint. [This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) contains a description of the message body to send.

As a brief (currently untested) example of a POST request. If you're project id was `fcm-test-12345`, you would make a POST request to:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fcm-test-12345/messages:send

The header should contain:

```
Authorization: Bearer <your access token>
Content-Type: application/json
```

And the body would be something like this:

```
{
  "message": {
    "data": { "key": "value" }, // optional data to send to client.
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification title",
        "body": "Notification body"
    },
    "token": "<client device token from MongoDB>"
  }
}
```